# How can I retrieve deleted objects from Active Directory with Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ldap

From the research I've done, it appears I need to send a special OID with my request (1.2.840.113556.1.4.417) in order to access the Deleted Objects container.

I couldn't find a way to send a specific control with a request using the "net-ldap" gem.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

There is another gem, ruby-ldap, which appears to be more flexible and it seems I *can* send controls with my request (e.g. using the search_ext2() method).

However, no matter what I try, I am not getting back any objects, even though I know they haven't been garbage collected yet.

I'm including the filter "isDeleted=TRUE" with my requests as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I finally figured it out.  One will need to use the `ruby-ldap` gem.  The reason my controls were not being sent was because the LDAP Protocol Version (`LDAP::LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION`) had defaulted to v2 and apparently it must be v3.

The following is a snippet that works:

```
require 'ldap'

conn = LDAP::Conn.new('yourserver.example.com', 389)
conn.set_option(LDAP::LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3)
conn.bind("CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com", "sekritpass")

# controlType: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.417 (LDAP_SERVER_SHOW_DELETED_OID)
control = LDAP::Control.new('1.2.840.113556.1.4.417')

conn.search_ext2('CN=Deleted Objects,DC=example,DC=com', LDAP::LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(isDeleted=*)", nil, false, [control], nil)
```

The filter `(isDeleted=*)` isn't necessarily required, you could also simply use `(objectClass=*)`.  You can also use the scope `LDAP::LDAP_SCOPE_ONELEVEL` if desired.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried isDeleted=* instead?

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978013.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too; same result.  No objects returned.

Comment: Thanks for trying Joshua, you may have the bounty

Comment: Thanks! - sorry it wasn't much help.